# How to add record for a specific user after the user logs in to the web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, active-directory

In my web application, user is authenticated using Active Directory and is logged in. Now, I need to add records for that specific user. In the database, there is a 'User' table with attributes 'UserID' and 'Code'. This userID is the same as the username used to login to the web app. The records for the user are added in the Record table with 'Code' as the foreign key. How can I add records which are automatically stored for the logged in user?

Comment: I assume you can already access the data in your database, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: And what do you mean by "automatically stored"?

Comment: I mean how can a user add a record (for example, food intake record) to his account. As the database will have records for different users, but the foreign key (primary key of user, Code) will depict the record for a specific user

Comment: Just add a record that includes the username... I still don't think I understand what you're asking.

Comment: A sample code would be helpful